# Does the order of protonation/deprotonation in the formation of hemiacetals matter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

In the mechanism depicted above, deprotonation occurs first and then protonation.
Can this order be changed? If not, why?

Comment: Yes you can change it and it's no problem. Just don't deprotonate the alcohol starting material and you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

The first (productive) step of this mechanism in acidic medium *MUST* be protonation of the carbonyl.  Alkoxides and hemiacetal-alkoxides have no appreciable concentration in acidic solutions, and the carbonyl is not a strong enough electrophile to be attacked by alcohol without protonation.

Comment: I realize now that teacher mentioned this rxn favors left side. but the rxn to the right side does occur, right? If a answer is yes, can you answer my original question?

Comment: Reaction rates are dependent on concentrations of reactants.  The concentration of a deprotonated alkoxide in aqueous solutions is dismally small, and hence its contribution to reaction rate negligible.

Comment: why should ROH be deprotonated to react? can't it just attack carbonyl carbon as nucleophile though this reaction is not preferred much?